# How does this speed limit question work?

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Now I might be heavily misguided and probably flat out wrong here, but this is an example question I got for using Rolle's Theorem and Mean Value Theorem:

[image]

How does this work? We can't determine if the speed ever surpasses 55 even using the theorems mostly because no equation of the speed nor distance nor acceleration of the car is given. I was just thinking of a counter example (correct me if I'm wrong), a straight line from 55 to 50 in [0, 4] minutes (or [0, 1/15] hours if using the correct units) never surpasses 55, another would be a negative parabola(correct this term if possible). My teacher says that since the average rate of change is 75mph (shouldn't it be -75mph since it DECREASES 5 miles in 4 minutes), that means the car must have reached 75mph at max. Now take my counterexample, it does indeed surpass 55...... at negative time, but the question specifically asks for the domain within the 4 minutes from the first station to the second station, what happened outside shouldn't have to matter.

Again I don't understand how this works, maybe there is something I'm missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Average was calculated *for* $t=0$ to $t=4$. There is no negative (or outside) time in this domain. In fact we have no information about anything outside this domain.

Comment: @cosmo5 yeah, thats what I was trying to say (probably got butchered). In my counter-example the only way the speed is ever greater than what we started with was if we go back in time, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: you didn't get butchered or anything. The point is just to realize that if I have, say, few natural numbers less than 10, then their average will never get larger than 10. To get this larger average, I must include one or few numbers larger than 10 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - if you forget about maths and just use common sense, it is clear that you cannot travel 5 miles in 4 minutes while staying under 75MPH.  Credit (+1) to your teacher (or whoever came up with it) for coming up with a question that relates this intuitive real world situation to the Mean Value Theorem.

Let $y(t)$ denote distance travelled in miles from the first station, at time $t$ measured in hours, with $t=0$ corresponding to the moment when the truck passed the first station.

Then $y(0)=0, y(\frac1{15})=5$.

If we assume that the truck's motion was continuous and differentiable on $[0,\frac1{15}]$, then we may apply the Mean Value Theorem, to get that at some $t\in [0,\frac1{15}]$, the speed of the truck $y'(t)$ is given by: $$
y'(t)=\frac{y(\frac1{15})-y(0)}{\frac1{15}-0}=\frac 5{\frac1{15}}=75{\rm MPH}
$$

Comment: I think I finally got it, so I was hung upon the speed of the car rather than the distance it traveled(which was why I made the terrible mistake of the -75mph, which I believe is the average deceleration), which if I had used that I would realize that the average speed of the car is far greater than the speed limit. This means that the 50mph and 55mph dont actually matter and instead that in between those 2 speeds(in relation to time) he clearly surpasses 75mph in order to make his average speed 75mph. I was too busy focusing on the speed I forgot about the distance the car travels.

Comment: @Apoqlite Yes that is a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that its distance $f(t)$ from the first station is a differentiable function of time $t$ over the stretch in question. We know that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/15)=5$, where times is measured in hours and distance in miles, so the average speed over the stretch in miles per hour is

$$\frac{5-0}{\frac1{15}-0}=75\,,$$

the slope of the secant line between the endpoints of the curve. The mean value theorem says that there is some $t_0$ between $0$ and $\frac1{15}$ such that $f'(t_0)=75$, i.e., some moment at which the truck’s speed was $75$ mph.